# run android activity on startup

Tags: java, android, startup

I'm trying to create an app that runs on startup. It's a simple program to display text that I want to display when I turn on my android device.
So far this is what I have:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" > 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity" > 
            <intent-filter > 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity> 

        <receiver android:name="com.mycompany.mybirthday.StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver> 
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.mybirthday; 

import android.app.*; 
import android.os.*; 
import android.view.*; 
import android.widget.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        // Do stuff
    } 
}
```

StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver.java

```
package com.mycompany.mybirthday; 

import android.app.*; 
import android.os.*; 
import android.view.*; 
import android.widget.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import android.content.*; 

public class StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
        context.startActivity(activityIntent); 
    } 
}
```

When I start my android, I get a message "Unfortunately, My Birthday stopped". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing what is/isn't happening, I can tell you that you need to include the flag `activityIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` when starting an `Activity` from outside of an `Activity`

Comment: Have you tried setting the <intent-filer> priority value and seeing if that affects things?

Comment: A logcat is always useful...